# ImportError: No module named enum on Mac Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, macos-mojave, usdz

I already had tried installing `enum`, `enum34` and `aenum` on my mac, but i could not import these packages into my code or interactive shell. 
But I can find these packages on `pip freeze`.

Basically I want to run https://github.com/kcoley/gltf2usd .

```
iMAC:Source JK$ pip install enum
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting enum
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from enum) (41.0.1)
Installing collected packages: enum
Successfully installed enum-0.4.7
```

```
from enum import Enum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named enum
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731316/908336) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27530579/908336). You may need to force-reinstall the `enum34` package: `pip install --ignore-installed enum34`

Comment: Thanks @MassoodKhaari was facing a similar issue on CentOS 8 and pip install --ignore-installed enum34 was the only thing that worked for me. I almost gave before coming across your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution but for now, I copied enum from **https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/enum34/src/default/enum/__init__.py** into my local folder.

Comment: can you specify the path of your local folder?

Comment: which one python? its :  `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: I use Python 3.7.3

Comment: sorry, into which folder did you copy enum? 
under ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages?

Comment: no, just copied into my project folder. luckily it was not something to work in a commercial purpose. @ Agile Bean